# Classification in a applied financial setting

Tags: classification

Many academic papers focusing on statistical learning in the applied setting of finance train a model such that their parameter set, B,  defines the relationship 
y(t) = B*x(t) + e(t)

y could be a 0-1 coded response for an increase (or not) of the asset price at time t.  Ignoring the details of the model my question is as follows: 
given that you are predicting the response at the SAME time that you record your features, how would you make use of this model?  Intuitively I think ok, my input space says we will 
see an increase in y but since they are at the same time, I can actually go and see what y has in fact done.  Do I take the view of my model to be the truth and create a trading signal based on this information (for example)?

Any practical insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to predict the future, and then use that information to profit, you need to build a model like this:
`Next(y)~x` or `y(t+1)=B*x(t)+e(t)`

i.e. specify your problem as "what will happen tomorrow" not "what did happen today."
Look at the [quantmod](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/index.html) package for R for more examples.

Comment: Yes, but all of your explanatory power goes out the window in this setting.  Besides, if it is this obvious why do so many academic papers ignore it?

Comment: @SpeedBoots Maybe the academic papers you are reading are focused on explaining the past rather than predicting the future.  Furthermore, it could be that there are certain variables that predict a stock's price going up.  The January effect would be an example of one such model.